# Can dx=dy happen when x and y are independent?

Tags: calculus

My question is pretty simple. can $dx=dy$ happen when x and y are independent random variable?

What I want to do here is to show that $\int f(x,y) dy =\int f(x,y) dx$, which are the marginal probability density function. I have assumed that x and y are independent random variables.

I guess this $\int f(x,y) dy =\int f(x,y) dx$ only satisfies when $dx=dy$.

Comment: I'm no expert, but I believe that $dx=dy$ is equivalent to $\frac{dy}{dx}=1$, or that $y=x+c$. I'm not really sure what you're asking though.

Answer (score 2):

The term $\int f(x,y)\,dx$ is a function of $y$ - let's call if F(y) and we compute this function as

$$F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dx$$

whereas the term $\int f(x,y)\,dy$ is a function of $x$ - let's call if G(x) and we compute this function as

$$G(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)\,dy$$

It is possible that $F$ and $G$ are of identical function form (e.g, if $f(x,y)=f(x+y)$).  However, the notation $\int f dx$ and $\int f dy$ are actually limits of Riemann sums.

In the former, the partition is taken along the x-axis while in the latter, the partition is taken along the y-axis.  These partitions are not related to one another and thus, it is meaningless to talk about their equality.

---

NOTE.

The density function for the case of independent random variables may be written as $f(x,y)=f_x(x)f_y(y)$.  Thus, the marginal density functions $F$ and $G$ are

$$F(y)=\int f(x,y)dx=\int f_x(x)f_y(y)dx=f_y(y)\int f_x(x)dx$$

$$G(x)=\int f(x,y)dy=\int f_x(x)f_y(y)dy=f_x(x)\int f_y(y)dy$$

Comment: But aren't the x-axis and the y-axis just copies of the Real line? Then a partition along the x-axis can be made into a partition along the x-axis.

Comment: They are independent partitions.

Comment: Right, but if you have an integral along the x-axis, it can be made naturally into a partition along the x-axis and viceversa. I think that is what the OP is after, though I am not sure.